# Is it possible to display a visual representation of a SCRIPT tag in CKEditor's WYSIWYG mode?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I have CKEditor allowing the insertion of a SCRIPT tag into the source, which works fine. But I'd like a visual representation of this in WYSIWYG mode so that the editor knows something is back there.

Can I show something in WYSIWYG mode which lets the editor know that there is a SCRIPT tag in the source at that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Show Protected](http://ckeditor.com/addon/showprotected) plugin.